# Populating Data Class via Simple Firebase Calls

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

Running into an error I have been researching and attempting to fix for the past couple weeks.  There are tons of suggestions out there and I've tried at least half a dozen with the same result each time.

How does Kotlin access Firebase data and populate a very simple data class?

> Error:       com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: 
>       Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.touchtapapp.handsofhope.LandingTextTitles

Read about suggestions to first convert to a Map and then to my custom data class... attempted this, successfully created the Mapped values w/ correct data... but ran into the exact same error when sending the Mapped values to the customs data class (LandingTextTitles).

Current code:

**Data Model Class**

```
data class LandingTextTitles(
        val subTitle: String,
        val title: String
)
```

**Method to retrieve data from firebase**

```
private fun initTitles() {

    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/landing")
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {


        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            p0.children.forEach {
                val titles = it.getValue(LandingTextTitles::class.java)
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            // Handle Cancelled Data            
        }
    })
        // Log the titles value to see if data passed correctly
        Log.d("Titles", titles.toString())

}
```

When I log out something like `Log.d(it.toString())`, I see the keys and values just fine.  What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**
[Firebase data snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pJXA.png)

**EDIT 2:**

If we use `Log.d("Titles", it.toString())`, we get the following:

```
D/Titles: DataSnapshot { key = subTitle, value = Start Here. }

D/Titles: DataSnapshot { key = title, value = Facing unexpected problems? }
```

Comment: Can you Please add the response snippet that you are getting from the firebase

Comment: What is the acutal contents of the database at the location of the query?  It seems that the actual contents are not what you think they are, since the error message is saying that you're trying to convert a String value into your object.

Comment: I have added a snapshot of the firebase data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the following database:

```
landing
   randomId
    subTitle : "Awesome"
    title    : "Developer Team"
```

Then you can retrieve `title` and `subTitle` by doing the following:

```
private fun initTitles() {

    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/landing")
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {


        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            p0.children.forEach {
                val title    = it.child("title").getValue(String::class.java)
                val subTitle = it.child("subTitle").getValue(String::class.java)

            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            // Handle Cancelled Data            
        }
    })
        // Log the titles value to see if data passed correctly
        Log.d("Titles", titles.toString())

}
```

If you want to use the data class, then change this:

```
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            p0.children.forEach {
                val titles = it.getValue(LandingTextTitles::class.java)
            }
```

into this:

```
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                val titles = p0.getValue(LandingTextTitles::class.java)
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I saw this solution during my research into this issue, and it works for me.  However, I feel there should be a way I can pass my Firebase data directly into a data class.  In my experience, it seems what I'm attempting to do would be a proper way to handle larger amounts of data eventually.  Perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: Wow - this worked!  I'm a little puzzled why I don't need the 'for each', the tutorial I was referencing does in fact require it, but it is a couple years out dated.  Perhaps this was changed with updates to Kotlin?

Thank you - this resolved my issue.

Comment: no it has nothing to do with kotlin.. When you looping using `forEach` the data that you are retrieving will be of type `String`, and when you use `getValue(LandingTextTitles::class.java)` then you are saying that you want to retrieve data of type `LandingTextTitles` thats why you get that error. So, you remove the `forEach` so firebase can correctly map the data retrieved to the class `LandingTextTitles`.

Comment: Excellent description.  I understand now.  Thanks!